# How to remove overridden settings from web.config programmatically

Tags: c#, iis-7, overriding

I have a rewrite rule configured in applicationHost.config and it is overridden in web.config.
Is there a way to remove overrides programmatically via Microsoft.Web.Administration API?
For example, here is a test rule in applicationHost.config:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="Default Web Site">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="TestRuleA" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                        <match url="A" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="A" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

And here is the same rule, but overridden in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="TestRuleA" />
                <rule name="TestRuleA" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="A_MODIFIED" />
                    <conditions />
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="A" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CUSTOM_RULE">
                    <match url="1" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="1" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'd like to remove any overrides at website level programmatically.
Here is the expected result in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                ... not test rule ...
                <rule name="CUSTOM_RULE">
                    <match url="1" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="1" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried to use RevertToParent, but it can be applied to the whole section, but I need to apply it only to my rewrite rule.
Is it possible?